# is it possible to create a single listview with different custom layouts in android ? if yes, how?

Tags: java, android, listview

I would like to create a listview that will have different custom layouts. Is it possible ? If yes, I would like to know how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idea of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)

I mark it as dupliacated... For any case, you can change your adater as below:

Implement (override) following method on your adapter:

```
int getViewTypeCount () {
   //return  the number of layouts that you have
   return 2;
}

int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //return the view type taht you want for each position...
    // for example, type 0 for position 0, 1,2, 3
    // type 1 for position 4 5 6
    if ( position >= 0 && position <= 3)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if (convertView == null) {
         // inflate layout acordind the view type
         // for type 0, inflate layout 1
         // for type 1, inflate layout 2
     }
     ....
     return convertView;
}
```

Android will re-use the views. However, it is smart enough to re-use views of the same type.

In my app for example, i have this to show a image when list is empty.. When the list has items, I show the list of items... Similar to Google Messaging app when the list is empty